# React Native Firebase RT Database Error - "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I have been trying to get Firebase Real Time Database to work. Though, I consistently get errors. I followed this [guide](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage) and have successfully gotten other packages from here working. I have the 16.5.0 version. The rules of the Database is set to true.

I installed React Native with Expo.

Code inside of a function:

```
database()
        .ref('/users/123')
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot) => {
            console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
        });
```

Database:

```
{
  "users": {
  "123": ""
  }
}
```

Calling of the function results in:

> TypeError: this._database.native.once is not a function. (In 'this._database.native.once(this.path, modifiers, eventType)', 'this._database.native.once' is undefined)

While hovering over database() VS Intellisense says:

> database(app?: ReactNativeFirebase.FirebaseApp | undefined): FirebaseDatabaseTypes.Module
> import database

I have tried different methods for database() and ref(), according to the documentations, but nothing seems to be working.

Anyone know why I get this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3379?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen
I did look it over, but it mainly concerned ios development, while I am currently working with the android build. It does appear in package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `npx expo run:android` and updating the Android Emulator solved the issue.